# Bash tells me permission is denied and then tells me that the command is invalid if I sudo

Tags: c++, bash, macos, sudo

I am trying to install the PyArt python lib, which has a technically optional dependence on the RSL TRMM C++ library.  (You can find PyArt here https://github.com/ARM-DOE/pyart and RSL TRMM here https://github.com/adokter/rsl.)

When I run `sh configure` on the RSL lib it works fine; however, when I run `make install` it give me this error:

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/librsl.1.dylib /usr/local/trmm/lib/librsl.1.dylib
install: /usr/local/trmm/lib/librsl.1.dylib: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 71
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

When I then run sudo make install to give it permissions, it gives me this error:

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C decode_ar2v install
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I have already tried `chmod 755 Makefile`.  The command completes but does not fix the error.

BTW I am on macOS 10.14.2 and obviously this is all in terminal.

Comment: Appropriate permissions are needed to install into `/usr/local` - that doesn't specifically require installing as root, but normal users normally don't have the required access. It will probably be necessary to ensure relevant environment variables (including path) are set correctly/consistently for both the configure and build - which is often easier if both are done by the same user to avoid conflicts due to different users having different environment variables set.   Often best to login or start a shell as root, set required variables, then configure, build, and install.

Comment: Did you try `sudo make install`?

Comment: @Peter You really should not be compiling stuff as root (or anything else that isn't root essential).

Comment: @Galik - in general terms, I agree.   However, I've encountered too many programs that come with configure scripts and makefiles which make that much harder than it should be - so it is necessary to take calculated risks (after reviewing the scripts and makefiles) to build and install programs.   On some OS (e.g. debian) such problems can be addressed by adding a user to a particular group, installing, then removing the user from that group.

Comment: The problem ended up being fixed by updating pip and reinstalling pyart itself.  The pyart library now had an install of rsl trmm that did not require root user access.  For the record, I never solved the underlying problem here and I am not sure what the solution is yet.

Comment: @Galik As I mentioned in the post when I sudo make install I recieve the error:

Comment: 'make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -C decode_ar2v install
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1'

Comment: @Peter how would I check which enviroment varibles need changing or are in conflict with the install?  I made sure that the path included the folder with the makefile is this what you ment?